# NSURL return nil?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsurl, null

i declared two NSString and NSURL variable in interface of my controller

```
// project file url
NSURL * url_projectURL;

// temp string just for examine
NSString * tempString;
```

in my app action named:

```
- (IBAction) btnNewProject:(id)sender

// after running save panel and clicked Save
// 
// set project url
url_projectURL = [savePanel URL];
// set temp string
tempString = [url_projectURL absoluteString];
//
NSLog(@"tempString is: %@", tempString);
NSLog(@"ProjectURL is: %@", [url_projectURL absoluteString]);
```

result is:

```
tempString is: file://localhost/Users/kosartofiq/Documents/project.ksf
ProjectURL is: file://localhost/Users/kosartofiq/Documents/project.ksf
```

but in other action for example: 
    - (IBAction) btn_test:(NSButton *)sender

```
NSLog(@"tempString is: %@", tempString);
NSLog(@"ProjectURL is: %@", [url_projectURL absoluteString]);
```

result:
for string variable is:

```
tempString is: file://localhost/Users/kosartofiq/Documents/project.ksf
```

but for url variable is nil or show error in running of coe

My question is why url variable changes it's value to nil and it lost it's value when use it in other action, but string variable keep it's value?
i want use this url to save changes to file and in my project i use it some time.

Comment: What is the variable saveProject: what class is it, how and where do you declare and assign a value to it?

Comment: saveProject is NSSavePanel. sorry for that i don't mentioned that i will change to savePanel. thanks

Comment: Please show the complete implementation of `btn_test:`.

Comment: implemention of btn_test if just for print nslogs not more , or print values in some text receiver (nstextfield) , i created just for test , i use those variable values in some procedure outside btn_test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're not using ARC, the problem is that you're assigning objects you don't own to instance variables. If the objects have no owners, they can be deallocated at any time. You should claim ownership of the objects, preferably by using accessors instead of directly setting the variables themselves.

Comment: i can't understand , can you explain with example? beside i use NSString just like NSURL , NSString don't lose it's value but other lose it's value

Comment: If you're going to directly assign, you need to do:  `url_projectURL = [[savePanel URL] retain];`  You have to retain objects you want to keep a reference to if you don't own them.  The fact that tempString is not losing its value is likely just luck.

Comment: @Kosar: No, it is **not** a bug in Xcode. That is one of the tricky things about bugs like this: They aren't guaranteed to do the wrong thing all the time — they just aren't guaranteed to do the right thing all the time either. The fact that URLs happen to be getting overwritten and some other objects aren't is just luck and unreliable implementation details.

Comment: thanks for advice "wades world" it's work.write your comment like answer. for your information just NSURL lose it's value , i have NSMutableDictionary like NSString don't lose it's value. without using retain code. maybe it some bug in Xcode 4.2.1 (i use this version)

Comment: ok @Chuck it mean is i use retain all the time for those variables i want use them as references?

Answer (score 0):

In your example code url_projectURL is a local variable, whereas tempString and projectURL are instance variables. You don't use projectURL in your action method.

Change all references to url_projectURL to projectURL in your action method to match your declaration.

Comment: sorry is misspelling , projectURL is url_projectURL , i will edit it and correct it.